# how to change android SearchView text

Tags: android, searchview

Is there a setText() method for SearchView or something like that?
I try to set the search text in the searchView like this but there is no method for like this.

```
searchView.setText(searchToken);
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

After wondering and trying I found out that there is a method in the API named setQuery() which you set the searchView text and you may choose to submit the search or not using the boolean parameter.

```
searchView.setQuery(searchToken, false);
```

Comment: Even after setting the boolean parameter false it still queries again.Any suggestions would help.

Comment: I've done this, but setting the 2nd param to `true` so the query gets executed as well, but note that though the query gets executed well, the text box stays blank, until when manually given focus. How would I ensure the auto-set value gets displayed automatically too?

Comment: it's OK.
 second argument is "submit"

Answer (score 41):

You can use `setQuery()` to change the text in the textbox.

However, `setQuery()` method triggers the focus state of a search view, so a keyboard will show on the screen after this method has been invoked.

To fix this problem, just call `searchView.clearFocus()` after `setQuery()` method to unfocus it and the keyboard will not show on the screen.

**Example:**

```
String suggestWord = intent.getDataString();
searchView.setQuery(suggestWord, false);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Not show since write searchView.setIconified(false); show .

Answer (score 17):

this is what worked for me

```
    MenuItem sItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) sItem.getActionView();

    sItem.expandActionView();
    searchView.setQuery("your text", false);
```

Comment: simple, quick life saving solution!

Comment: this works but after adding this code, menu option shows 3 dots. I don't want to show 3 dots, I jus want to show icons!

Comment: your menu item should have `appcompat:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: `sItem.expandActionView();` this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 10):

If you want pre-fil your `SearchView` with some text `searchView.setQuery(text, false)` would not work out of the box. the reason is when `SearchView` gets expanded

`searchView.onActionViewExpanded()`

get called which calls `searchView.setText("")` and clears any text we have set.

Solution is to set an Expand listener and set the pre-fil text once the `SearchView` is expanded

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
        override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            // it is important to call this before we set our own query text.
            searchView.onActionViewExpanded()
            searchView.setQuery("Prefil Text", false)
            return true
        }

        override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?) = true
    })
    return true
}
```

Comment: Great answer. But beware of  **searchView.onActionViewExpanded()** and **searchView.setQuery()** _both_ triggering **onQueryTextChange()** if you have deployed **searchView.setOnQueryTextListener**. The first trigger may very well empty the String about to be supplied to the second trigger.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the searchView to expand and it can be shrink back to an icon after the user tap x (close), the way is:

```
searchView.isIconified = false // Expand it
searchView.setQuery("your text here", false) // true if you want to submit, otherwise false
searchView.clearFocus() // so the keyboard is not show up.
```

NOTE: 
If you expand it using:

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded()
```

searchView will not shrink back after user tap x (close)