# How to set searchview text in Android

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I try to find a method for setting text for SearchView but I can't find anything? does any one know any method for doing this ? for example something like this

```
 searchView.setText("blah blah");
```

Comment: Use intent.putExtra.

Comment: are you getting the intented data/query in this activity

Comment: i believe ur problem is not how to getting string from intent but how to searching programmatically using search view

check this answer sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426769/how-to-change-android-searchview-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change android SearchView text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426769/how-to-change-android-searchview-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this use **setQuery**

> **[setQuery(CharSequence query, boolean submit)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)**
>
> Sets a query string in the text field and optionally submits the query as well.

**sample code**

send title to other activity using intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TITLE", "NILESH");
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrive title in other activity like this

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("TITLE");
searchView.setQuery(str, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//1st activity
Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(), 2ndActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", someValue);
startActivity(intent);


//2nd activity
String value="";
Intent intent=getIntent();
Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
if(bundle!=null)
{
  mealId=bundle.getString("key");
}
```

Since you had get value in 2nd activity, other things are simple.